# Update Document - Average of Previous Documents Filtered by Date

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a lot of documents like:

```
{
  _id: something
  date: 2017-10-23 20:05:00.000 (Date)
  qty: 400.41 (Double)
  weight: 100.44 (Double)
}
```

I need to update each document by adding 2 fields: qty_avg and weight_avg that are calculated by the average of the elements that are at maximum 5 minutes behind the date.

The tools I have at my disposal are python, or mongo console, the latter would be preferable if possible

Comment: As a "moving window"? You don't "aggregate" for that, you "iterate a cursor". Even with the upcoming release, forcing a type of "join" would be overkill. I would be far more simple to iterate the cursor keeping the "last 5 minutes values" and then calculating relative to each document.

Comment: yes, exactly a moving window, but i need the data stored for further operations and dataviz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in comment, this is not an "aggregation" query. And aggregation does not "update" itself, but rather returns results which you could "optionally" output to a **new** collection, or simply iterate the cursor.

What you are actually asking for involves "iterating the cursor", where you essentially keep a record of the last values within the timeframe then calculate and update the document accordingly.

With pymongo, but still relatively the same practice for any language:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

docBuffer = []
writeBuffer = []

for doc in collection.find().sort('date',pymongo.ASCENDING):
  docBuffer.append(doc)        # Add to buffer

  # Filter buffer for expired
  docBuffer = filter(lambda x: x['date'] >= (doc['date'] - timedelta(minutes=5)), docBuffer)

  writeBuffer.append({
    "updateOne": {
      "filter": { "_id": doc['_id'] },
      "update": {
        "$set": {
          "qty_avg": reduce(lambda x,y: y['qty'] + x, docBuffer, 0) / len(docBuffer),
          "weight_avg": reduce(lambda x, y: y['weight'] + x, docBuffer, 0) / len(docBuffer)
        }
      }
    }
  })

  # Write if buffer has enough to make a bulk write
  if len(writeBuffer) > 1000:
    collection.bulk_write(writeBuffer);
    writeBuffer = []

# Clear any buffered writes
if len(writeBuffer) > 0:
  collection.bulk_write(writeBuffer);
  writeBuffer = []
```

Or plain JavaScript for the shell. Not very different:

```
var docBuffer = [],
   writeBuffer = [];

db.collection.find().sort({ "date": 1 }).forEach( doc => {
  docBuffer.push(doc);

  docBuffer = docBuffer.filter( x => x.date.valueOf() > (doc.date - (1000 * 60 * 5)) );

  writeBuffer.push({
    "updateOne": {
      "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
      "update": {
        "$set": {
          "avg_qty": docBuffer.reduce((x,y) => y.qty + x, 0 ) / docBuffer.length,
          "avg_weight": docBuffer.reduce((x,y) => y.weight + x, 0 ) / docBuffer.length
        }
      }
    }
  });

  if (writeBuffer.length > 1000) {
    db.collection.bulkWrite(writeBuffer);
    writeBuffer = [];
  }

});

if (writeBuffer.length > 0) {
  db.collection.bulkWrite(writeBuffer);
  writeBuffer = [];
}
```

So basically you are going though each document and keeping the relevant data in a list. You really only need the date, and fields you want an average from here, but just pushing the whole document because it's small in your question. Then you [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) that list for any dates older than the required "window" so that they are removed.

Then we come to writing back to the collection, using [`bulk_write()`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write) here because it's the most efficient thing to do as it only actually writes when we tell it to, and does so in "batches" so that each document processed is not immediately resulting in it's own write and slowing the process. There is less overhead this way.

All we do is [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) the new fields, calculating the average values from the "buffer" list of entries still remaining after we filtered the dates that were "expired" from the window.

And that's basically it.

---

## MongoDB 3.6 - Possible to Join, but not optimal.

When MongoDB 3.6 is released, it would be "possible" to run an aggregation with a "join" condition using the new "sub-pipeline" of `$lookup`. But it's really nowhere near as optimal as the cursor for the obvious reason of self referencing for every item:

```
[
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "collection",
    "vars": { "currDate": "$date" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": {
          "$and": [
            { "$gte": ["$date", { "$subtract": ["$$currDate", (1000 * 60 * 5 )] }] },
            { "$lte": ["$date", "$$currDate"] }
          ]
        }
      }}
    ],
    "as": "buffer"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "date": 1,
    "qty": 1,
    "weight": 1,
    "avg_qty": { "$avg": "$buffer.qty" },
    "avg_weight": { "$avg": "$buffer.weight" }
  }}
]
```

That's basically the only way you get such a "window" from an "aggregation", and as you can see it's not really much of an "aggregation" at all, and simply a contrived "join" condition to allow the "skip back" to get the relative dates to the current document.

So you generally are far better off sticking with the cursor, even if it does mean that the write process cannot be wholly contained on the server itself and requires some over the wire communication.